# Tool that can turn this kind of particular screw in upright piano?

Tags: piano, maintenance, repair

I tried to search in piano anatomy and glossaries but couldn't find any result. I also tried google search with image and it incorrectly identified my picture as "webbing". Can anyone help me identify the tool I can use to turn this particular kind of screw in upright piano? (Or tell me how to find related resources?) See picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That screw is known as the "[let-off regulating screw](http://www.concertpitchpiano.com/UprightActionModel.html)" (see part #28 in the linked diagram). Yours appears to be a "spade screw" (below). To adjust it, you need a "Piano let-off regulating screwdriver" like the one shown below.

**space screw**
[image: spade screw]

**Regulating screwdriver**
[image: Regulating screwdriver]
([Image source](https://www.howardpianoindustries.com/7-regulating-screwdriver/))